# Replace using regular expression in QGIS: how to mask a dot (point)?

Tags: qgis, string, replace, regular-expression

In QGIS, I have a string with the pattern `(1 character)(1 character)(dot)(number with 1 or more digits)`.

How can I use `regexp_replace()` to get the number only?

I tried `regexp_replace('ab.27',('(\\D\\D(.))(\d)'),('\2'))`, but output is `'?27'`, where I want `'27'`.

How to mask the dot?

**Edit**

As I have a longer string then just what I presented here for sake of shortness as `'ab.27'` and this longer string might also contain digits, I must be able to identify the pattern mentioned above.

So the strings might look as (`->` for what I want to achieve):

```
354ab.27 -> 27
ab.27fg87 -> 27
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can search for any char (`.*`), followed by a dot (`\\.`), followed by a number that we capture (`(\\d+)`) followed by any char. Replace with the captured number.

```
regexp_replace('354ab.27xyz789','.*\\.(\\d+).*','\\1')
```

or you can search for a dot followed by a number that we capture

```
regexp_matches('354ab8.27xyz789','\\.(\\d+)')
```

---

Original answer for a pattern of `(1 character)(1 character)(dot)(number with 1 or more digits)`:

Instead of searching for the exact pattern, you can search for what is not a number and replace it with an empty string:

```
regexp_replace('ab.27','[^0-9]','')
```

or you can look for numbers only

```
regexp_matches('ab.27','(\\d+)')
```

But if you are always having the same pattern, you can just take all chars but the first 3 ones:

```
right('ab.27',length('ab.27')-3)
```

Comment: The unfathomable depths of regular expressions.

Comment: :-) Specifically for QGIS as it is almost but not completely following the standards...

Comment: These three expressions work for the example provided, indeed. However, I have longer strings with digits before that - so I must find the pattern `(char)(char)(dot)(digits)`. Will update the quesiton accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Base on your regular expression, you can use this:

`regexp_replace('ab.27',('(\\D\\D\\.)'), (''))` returns `27`.

`ab.123456` returns `123456`.

Comment: Indeed. However, I was not so clear in my initial question to make the issue a bit easier - see edit.